# What is the best approach to ping my APIs on a scheduled basis?

Tags: .net, rest, asp.net-web-api2, health-monitoring

We have an API suite. Some of the endpoints are used infrequently and any issues that may arise infrastructure-wise or through any other source may go unnoticed for these infrequently used ones as compared to the highly used ones.

Is there a open-source solution that I can use/customize  to ping my API endpoints regularly on a scheduled basis so that health is maintained all through.

Comment: i use https://uptimerobot.com/ for this purpose (has free and paid plans)

Comment: Look into http://cloudmonix.com - it's not open source or free, but supports montioring XML/JSON endpoints and even let you alert on the data that they return

Answer (score 0):

You can consider Microsoft's Application Insights - it supports synthetic tests from 16 locations around the world, and presents the results in easily consumable format, also supporting alerting and data export... And the basic offering is free 
[I am part of Application Insights team]